# Does the zero that follows the fractional second part of a Jodatime formatted Date changes its Comparable order?

Tags: java, date-format

Given two strings:

```
a) 2013-05-02 02:11:05.24
b) 2013-05-02 02:11:05.240
```

Does joda time interpret these two to have the same Comparable order ? i.e. they are equivalent.

Comment: Without knowing anything about joda-time, I would imagine the time is represented internally as something more primitive and its string representation is irrelevant to its comparison.

Comment: In any case, it would be easy enough to test, especially if you already have it set up.  Just parse both strings into a DateTime, and check for equality.

Comment: .24 and .240 does not equivalent unless they first one representing 1/100th of a second and second one representing number of milliseconds. And joda time does not supports 1/100th of seconds (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)